# Defining defaults in Postgres updateable views

Tags: postgresql, view

If we were to have a view such as this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.comedies AS 
SELECT name, release_date
FROM films
WHERE type = 'Comedy'
```

we would have a view of only comedies, but obviously not the type column.  From reading the docs it sounds like if I were to insert into this view, the type may not get set to the value in the WHERE:

> If an automatically updatable view contains a WHERE condition, the
>   condition restricts which rows of the base relation are available to
>   be modified by UPDATE and DELETE statements on the view. However, an
>   UPDATE is allowed to change a row so that it no longer satisfies the
>   WHERE condition, and thus is no longer visible through the view.
>   Similarly, an INSERT command can potentially insert base-relation rows
>   that do not satisfy the WHERE condition and thus are not visible
>   through the view.

Assuming this to be true - how can I assure that all data inserted/updated through that view has the correct type?

Comment: You need an `instead of` trigger

Comment: Care to elaborate in an answer?